# How to php pagination of results obtained from this database

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am a beginner in php. 
I visualize in my html page the results obtained with this php code, and now I want to paginate the results and limit your search to 6 items per page. How can I get this? My php code is as follows:

```
<?php
$k = $_GET['k'];
$terms = explode(" ", $k);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ";

$i = 0;
foreach ($terms as $each){
    $i++;
    if ($i == 1)
        $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    else
        $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
}

// connect
mysql_connect("hostname","databaseUser","databasePassword");
mysql_select_db("databaseName");

$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

echo "<p><strong>Totale: {$numrows} risultati trovati</strong></p></br>";

if ($numrows > 0){

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $keywords = $row['keywords'];
    $link = $row['link'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    $caption = $row['caption'];

    echo "<h4><a href='$link'>$title</a></h4>";
    echo "<em>$description</em></br></br>";
    echo "$caption</br>";
    echo "$link</br></br>";
    echo "<em>$date</em></br></br>";

    }

}
else
    echo "NO result found  for \"<p><strong>$k</strong></p>\"";

// disconnect
mysql_close();
```

?>

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a page variable into your code. The easiest way to to this is via $_GET, just like you grabbed keywords, so your url should look something like this:

```
foo.php?k=keywords%20here&p=1
```

Where p is the current page number.

Then you just need to add a limit to your search results so that you only grab 6, and the correct 6 at that. Something like this:

```
$query .= ' LIMIT '.(6*($pageNum - 1)).' 6';
```

This statement tells SQL to start at the first entry for the given page, and grab 6 results. We subtract 1 from the page number so that page 1 starts at entry 0 instead of entry 6.

The result of this code:

```
page | statement  | Rows Grabbed
---------------------------------
1    | LIMIT 0 6  | 1-6
2    | LIMIT 6 6  | 7-12
3    | LIMIT 12 6 | 13-18
---------------------------------
and so on...
```

You might need to check that $_GET['p'] is an integer before you put it in $pageNum, so that you don't run into runtime issues trying to multiply a string by 6.

If you ever want to change the results per page, simply replace the 6's in that statement with the desired number of results per page, e.g.

```
$query .= ' LIMIT '.($numResults*($pageNum - 1)).' '.$numResults;
```

That way you can set your desired number of results with another variable, say $_GET['n'] or something similar, and have even better control.

EDIT:

You should probably add error checking:

```
$pageNum = (is_numeric($_GET['p']) ? intval($_GET['p']) : 1);
```

which says if GET[p] is numeric, set pageNum to the integer value of GET[p]. Otherwise, set pageNum to 1.

Also, You have a few errors in the way that you put variables into strings. There are two ways to join a variable into a string, you can either use double quotes and curly braces, like so:

```
$string = "this string has {$variable} in it";
```

Or you can concatenate with periods, using either single or double quotes likes so:

```
$string = 'this string has ' . $variable . " in it";
```

You have this problem in your foreach loop when you append the query, and also further down where you output your results.

Comment: I understand the reasoning but I do not know how to modify the above code. Can you kindly do this for me? You'd be a great help for me

Comment: After `$k = $_GET['k'];`, add `$pageNum = $_GET['p'];`. Then after your foreach loop, add `$query .= ' LIMIT '.(6*($pageNum - 1)).' 6';`. Then, whenever you access the site, be sure to have a page number in the url, eg `foo.php?k=keywords%20here&p=1`. You'll need to add page number links and things like that, but this is the basic framework behind it.

Comment: I have: 
undefined index: p
$pageNum = $_GET['p'];

mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given..
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

Comment: You should probably add error checking, eg: `$pageNum = (is_numeric($_GET['p']) ? intval($_GET['p']) : 1);`, which says if GET[p] is numeric, set pageNum to the integer value of GET[p]. Otherwise, set pageNum to 1.

Comment: I always error ... looks like I should not be able to find a solution. I'm frustrated.

Comment: `$query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";` and the following $query line is where your problems are. You should wrap $each in curly braces like so: `$query .= "keywords LIKE '%{$each}%' ";`. Variables inside of a string need to either be wrapped in curly braces, or concatenated instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is a problem that most of us have tried to solve over the years.

You can build your own library to do this but you'll almost definitely be re-inventing the wheel and might not spot/handle some of the special cases.

If you're using a framework I'd suggest using the built in paginator, if not you could look at using something like http://pear.php.net/package/Pager which is a PEAR package.